# Finding where an integral is positive or negative given the graph of the function.

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives, graphing-functions

This problem on my math test was slightly confusing, as I was not sure how to solve it:
[image]

I am guessing that since the integral is positive or negative, we can find where the derivative is increasing and decreasing, and apply the same intervals for the question.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you see that $g(0)=0?$ And that $g>0$ on $(0,4]?$

Comment: $g(x)$ is area under the graph bounded by lines $t=0$ and $t=x$.

Comment: @zhw, yes that is quite obvious. However, I am unsure whether the problem is simply asking for this: g(x) > 0 on [-4,-3] U [0,4], g(x) < 0 on [-3,0] U [4,6]. Is this the case?

Comment: No, that is far from the case.

Answer (score 1):

In the comments you agreed $g(0)= 0,$ $g>0$ on $(0,4].$ What about $g(5)?$ Now we encounter area that is to be subtracted, namely the area of that triangle. But the area of that triangle is clearly less than the area that gives $g(4).$ So we have $g>0$ on $(0,5].$ Now think about $g$ on $[5,6].$

For $x<0,$ recall that $\int_0^x f = - \int_x^0 f$ by definition. Because $f<0$ on $(-3,0)$ we will therefore have $g>0$ on $[-3,0).$ Keeping that in mind, visually inspect the graph to see what happens for $x<-3.$